# question about taylor series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

[image]

Can someone explain why 1 and 2 use different Taylor series? Why i cant use $1/(1+r)$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{inf}(-1)^n r^n$ on 2,vice versa?

Comment: One is around $\;2\;$ , the other one is around $\;1\;$ ....things must change if we want the series to converge *close* to the pivot point chosen.

Comment: but if I use 1/(1+r) =$\sum_{n=0}^{inf}(-1)^n r^n$ on 2 , is it still correct?

Comment: Where *exactly* in 2 and with what $\;r\;$, @puppylord ?

Comment: I could make x+2-2/x+2 like question1, then $1-(2/(x+2))= 1-(1/(1+(x/2))$ and use =1/(1+r)= $\sum_{n=0}^{inf}(-1)^n r^n$

Comment: And how do you obtain that way a series power around $\;2\;$ , @puppylord? You **have** to get a power series in $\;x-2\;$ ...!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach.

$$ \frac{x}{2x+1} = \frac{x}{2(x+1/2)}=\frac{(x-2)+2}{2( (x-2)+5/2 )}= \frac{(x-2)+2}{5(1+ 2(x-2)/5 )} $$

$$ = \frac{(x-2)}{5(1+ 2(x-2)/5 )} + \frac{2}{5(1+ 2(x-2)/5 )} . $$

Now, put $t=\frac{2}{5}(x-2)$ in the last equation and work out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confussion stems from the fact we're not sure what "around $\;x=c\;$" *really* means. This means that you have to get a series of the form

$$f(x)=f(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$$

Thus, in (2) you need a series of the form

$$f(1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n$$

and likewis with $\;(x-2)\;$ for (1).

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand. Both question are very similar, but use different solution. Does that mean if c = 1 I use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-c)^n$, and when c is larger than 1 ,I use $\sum_{n=0}^{infty}(-1)^n r^n$?

Comment: No @puppylord...I think you need to *very carefully* read an introduction to power (Taylor) series. The last one is using, apparently, $\;r\;$ a variable so it is a series around **zero**

Comment: sorry i have an exam coming up today, if you dont mind telling me a trick when do I use the $\sum_{n=0}^{infty}(-1)^n r^n$ and when it is not? thank you!